# Gnome Terminal primary selection and Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V clipboard sync needed

Tags: gnome-terminal, sync, clipboard-manager

I was putty user. Putty allows you to select the text which gets copied to clipboard. Now on ubuntu, I am using Terminal to connect host.

I want to sync clipboard and terminal primary selection. So I want some thing like this

1. Mouse selection of text in Terminal updates clipboard and primary selection
   (Right now,it just updates primary selection)
2. Any text copy (Via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) outside terminal (some other program) should sync both. Right now it just updates clipboard. e.g. text in gedit

I found various programs like parcellite, Glippy, Pastie, Diodon, Clipit. All this programs are excellent but they have 1 annoying feature (atlest for me). These programs updates both primary and clipboard even if I select any text outside terminal via Mouse. I do not want this feature and I am not able to find any means to turn them off.

For example

1. I select text in terminal via mouse
2. I select text in firefox via mouse <- this will update both clipboard and primary
3. I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> in terminal <- this will paste text from firefox where as I do not want this. Mouse selected text outside terminal should not be reflected in clipboard

Friends do you have any pointers for me. How can I achieve this.I do not want to use Putty in ubuntu as it has very bad UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose one of these: klipper or glipper or [parcellite](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/) or clipit and install it with `sudo apt install <package>`

Both [this](https://superuser.com/questions/74211/glipper-panel-application-doesnt-load-on-startup) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/42991/clipboard-manager-for-ubuntu) posts on superuser have more info.

> dpkg-query -l *lipper

ii  glipper        1.0-1.1ubuntu1 Clipboard manager for the GNOME panel
ii  klipper        4:4.4.2-0ubunt clipboard utility for KDE 4

> dpkg-query -l parce*

ii  parcellite     0.9.2-1        lightweight GTK+ clipboard manager