# How to paste github-copied links into terminal with shift+insert

Tags: command-line, clipboard

GitHub allows for copying git links with ui element under 'Code' button. When I click it, I can paste in terminal with with rightclick->paste, but not with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>. If I copy the link manually with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it can be pasted with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>. This double clipboard behavior is extremely frustrating, so I would like to get rid of it completely and just use one clipboard everywhere.

Comment: Why don't you just paste by using the middle mouse button? Doesn't that work?

Comment: Related: [Gnome Terminal primary selection and Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V clipboard sync needed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31942/gnome-terminal-primary-selection-and-ctrlc-ctrlv-clipboard-sync-needed) , [Inconsistent copy and paste behaviour. Is there a fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12047/inconsistent-copy-and-paste-behaviour-is-there-a-fix)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the good habit of pasting into the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. That always works.

You can also use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy from the terminal.